# How to get VS to use local build of ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I've cloned dotnet/aspnetcore, switched to the `release/3.1` branch, and followed all the steps in [`BuildFromSource.md`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/docs/BuildFromSource.md) to get a local build of ASP.NET Core 3.1.10 built and installed. I'm using the `startvs.cmd` in the root of the repo to run my own VS solution containing an ASP.NET Core project. When I build and run my ASP.NET Core 3.1 sln and check the Debug > Modules window, I can see that the locally-built 3.1.10 DLLs are indeed being loaded - all good.

However, if I check my ASP.NET Core project's referenced frameworks (Project > Dependencies > Frameworks) I see the following:

- `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`: path `C:\Users\iank.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.app.ref\3.1.8`, version 3.1.8
- `Microsoft.NETCore.App`: path `C:\aspnetcore.dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\3.1.0`, version 3.1.0

`Microsoft.NETCore.App` looks correct, but I would expect that `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` would be using `C:\aspnetcore\.dotnet\packs\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref\3.1.10` (which exists) - that isn't the case. The end result is that instead of building against my local 3.1.10, VS is building against the release 3.1.8, which is not what I want.

**How do I make VS build using the 3.1.10 ASP.NET Core DLLs?** Do I have to define a new/unique `FrameworkReference` that points to my 3.1.10 DLLs?

Comment: What is the project properties Target Net version?

Comment: Target Framework is .NET Core 3.1. But I don't think that's relevant for ASP.NET Core, which uses the pseudo-SDK of `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` in the `project.csproj` which (as far as I understand) resolves to a particular version of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` - in this case, the wrong version.

Comment: Starting with Net 4.7.2 you should have capability of targeting either Net or Core.

Comment: For anyone still looking for an answer, the right approach is to use `KnownFrameworkReference` overrides as explained in [this Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/27291#issuecomment-729938938)